# Thrust filter by key value

Tags: filter, cuda, gpu, thrust

In my application I have a class like this:

```
class sample{
    thrust::device_vector<int>   edge_ID;
    thrust::device_vector<float> weight;
    thrust::device_vector<int>   layer_ID;

/*functions, zip_iterators etc. */

};
```

At a given index every vector stores the corresponding data of the same edge.

I want to write a function that filters out all the edges of a given layer, something like this:

```
void filter(const sample& src, sample& dest, const int& target_layer){
      for(...){
        if( src.layer_ID[x] == target_layer)/*copy values to dest*/;
      }
}
```

The best way I've found to do this is by using `thrust::copy_if(...)` [(details)](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__stream__compaction.html#gafd4cd96b998ad2b3c336be1e24dc1f67)

It would look like this:

```
void filter(const sample& src, sample& dest, const int& target_layer){
     thrust::copy_if(src.begin(),
                     src.end(),
                     dest.begin(),
                     comparing_functor() );
}
```

**And this is where we reach my problem**:

The `comparing_functor()` is an unary function, which means I cant pass my `target_layer` value to it.

Anyone knows how to get around this, or has an idea for implementing this while keeping the data structure of the class intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass specific values to functors for use in the predicate test in addition to the data that is ordinarily passed to them.  Here's a worked example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#define DSIZE 10
#define FVAL 5

struct test_functor
{
  const int a;

  test_functor(int _a) : a(_a) {}

  __device__
  bool operator()(const int& x ) {
    return (x==a);
    }
};

int main(){
  int target_layer = FVAL;
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_vals(DSIZE);
  thrust::sequence(h_vals.begin(), h_vals.end());
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_vals = h_vals;
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(DSIZE);
  thrust::copy_if(d_vals.begin(), d_vals.end(), d_result.begin(),  test_functor(target_layer));
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_result = d_result;
  std::cout << "Data :" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_vals.begin(), h_vals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Filter Value: " << target_layer << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Results :" << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_result.begin(), h_result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```